# How do I bind UserControl property?

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

Let's say I have a simple UserControl with no codebehind:

```
<UserControl
xmlns= ....
x:Class="TrafficLight.LightControl">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<Grid x:Name="Light" >
  <Ellipse  x:Name="MyColor" Fill="{**I need bind this field to UserControl.Foreground**}" Stroke="#FF000000" />
  <Ellipse  x:Name="Shade" Fill="#E4555555" />
</Grid>
</Grid>
```

And use this UserControl on the Page:

```
<TrafficLight:LightControl x:Name="red" Foreground="#FFFEF100" **<= I need to bind MyColor.Fill with this property**/>
```

How I can implement this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I looked into various methods and without ElementName binding (something that Silverlight 3 introduces), which Microsoft didn't include for Silverlight, it's a tough one. Without some code behind, this is not an easy task to achieve.

[This blog post](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/wpf/2009/02/relativesource-binding-in-silverlight/) gives some detail on how you could achieve this, but be aware that you will need to write some code.

Comment: Thanks. I've try to use it, but no effect.
<Ellipse x:Name="Color">
  <TL:BindingHelper.Binding>
    <TL:BindingProperties TargetProperty="Fill"
     SourceProperty="Foreground"
     RelativeSourceSelf="False"
     ElementName="MyUserControlName"/>
  </TL:BindingHelper.Binding>
</Ellipse>

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame. I'll try and take a look later today, and see if we can't sort this one out for you. :)